# Function codomain

Tags: functions

Suppose that function $f:P^2\to K$ where $P$**={0,1,2,...100}** is defined as

$f(x,y)=x^2+ 5y^2$

How a set $K$ should be defined since its maximal element depends on domain of a function and function itself?

Answer (score 0):

To define a function, you need to state:

- the domain
- the rule
- the codomain

We do not have to state the range, you just have to make sure that it contains its range. The answer is not unique.

$\forall (x,y) \in P^2$, can you find the minimal value and maximal value that $f(x,y)$ can take? You are given the domain and the rule, so this should be computable.

Think of can $f$ be negative? to make $f$ as large as possible, which $x$ and $y$ should be picked.

Comment: Yes, minimal and maximal value are computable, but i want to know is there a way to define $K$ without computing it? Or i should simply define $f:\mathbb{N}^2\to \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: You are already given $P^2$ as your domain. If you want to define $K$ be $\{ 0 \} \cup \mathbb{N}$, I can't say that you are wrong as well.

Comment: In fact, it is important to define a domain, since only these values are valid for this function, and a mapping rule. These two things will define a codomain which does not need to be defined strictly, i.e. a set $K$ can be defined as a subset of any already defined set.